# Iterating through an array to find text in a <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

So I have this piece of HTML here:

```
<span id="titletextonly">Some awesome text</span>
```

With this Javascript:

```
let divs= $("#titletextonly");
let array = ['wow', "text"];

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   if (array.includes(divs[i].innerHTML)) {
    divs.css("background-color","red");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it to find if a piece of text in the array is in  element.

With the code right now, it will only highlight the text if it is exactly the text, no little chunks of text like I have right now

Any help to refine the code would be great!

Comment: Can you please provide a working and non working jsfiddle example?

Comment: Use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting using `id` there is no need to loop over it

```
// target the element
let divs = $("#titletextonly");
 // array of matched element
let array = ['wow', "text"];

// loop over the array and get each item
array.forEach(function(item) {
   // Now check if the selected text have this item
   // if the item is found in the string, then add background color
  if (divs.text().trim().indexOf(item !== -1)) {
    divs.css("background-color", "red")
  }
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bmja03v4/)

Comment: Why not create a stack snippet? Its better to make answer independent of any redirection

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here: `array.includes(divs[i].innerHTML)`

It would look like: `['wow', "text"].includes("Some awesome text")`. But you wish to match individual words in statement and not entire statement. For this, you will have to loop over texts and on words in array to find match.

#### Sample:

```js
let divs = $(".titletextonly");
let array = ['wow', "text"];

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (array.some((x)=>divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf(x)>-1)) {
    divs.eq(i).css("background-color", "red");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="titletextonly">Some awesome text</span>
<span class="titletextonly">Some random words</span>
```

---

**$.each approach**

Since you are already using jQuery to fetch elements, you can use `$.each` and `$().text()` or `$().html()` instead of `.innerHTML`.  Its always better to keep the approach consistent.

```js
let divs = $(".titletextonly");
let array = ['wow', "text"];

$(".titletextonly").each(function(i, el) {
  if (array.some((x) => $(el).text().indexOf(x) > -1))
    $(el).css("background-color", "red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="titletextonly">Some awesome text</span>
<span class="titletextonly">Some random words</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for every item in your array whether it is included in one of your divs, like:

```js
let divs = $("#titletextonly");
let array = ['wow', "text"];

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (divs[i].innerHTML.includes(array[j])) {
      divs.eq(i).css("background-color", "red");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="titletextonly">Some awesome text</span>
```

Comment: I have wrapped your code in snippet but there is an error. *"Uncaught TypeError: divs[i].css is not a function"* Please edit as per your ease.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the wrapping, couldn't easily do that on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#some` method to iterate over your `array` of strings and check whether any of your `divs` include each snippet of text:

```js
let divs = $('#titletextonly')
let array = ['wow', 'text']

divs.each(function (i) {
  array.some(function (text) {
    return this.text().includes(text) && this.css('background-color', 'red')
  }, $(this))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="titletextonly">Some awesome text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like this.

```js
let divs = $(".titletextonly");
let array = ['wow', "text"];
    
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    let innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML || divs[i].text();
    for(let item of array) {
        let regex = new RegExp(item, 'g');
        let targetStr = `<span style="background-color: red">${item}</span>`;
        innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(regex, targetStr)
    }
    $(divs[i]).html(innerHTML); 
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="titletextonly">Some awesome text</div>
    <div class="titletextonly">Some wow awesome text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using innerHTML will destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM! Use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your matched divs, then loop over the array match values.  Compare the two strings using `.includes()`; styling can be applied using CSS classes:

```js
let $divs = $('.text');
let array = ['wow', 'text'],
  len = array.length;

$divs.each(function() {
  let $div = $(this);
  for (var i = 0, n = len; i < n; i++) {
    if ($div.text().includes(array[i])) {
      $div.addClass('matched');
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.matched {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Wow wow wee wow</div>
<div class="text">This doesn't have it</div>
<div class="text">This does have text</div>
```